# Name for the integrand used when computing arc length

Tags: calculus, integration, terminology, arc-length

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function, and consider the curve $\Gamma$ described by $y = f(x)$ over a closed interval $[a, b]$.  As is well-known from basic Calculus, the arclength of $\Gamma$ can be calculated by computing the integral
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{ 1 + \left( f'(x) \right)^2 } \, dx$$

My question concerns the integrand, considered as a function in its own right:  what (if anything) is it *called*?  That is, for a given function $f(x)$, is there a name for the function
$$g(x) = \sqrt{ 1 + \left( f'(x) \right)^2 } ?$$

It feels like this is connected (sort of ) to a Jacobian but I can't quite articulate how.  The best I have come up with is "arc length element function for $f$" but I'd like to know if there is a better name or more elegant way of describing this.

Comment: The only "name" that I can come up with would be with the  "dx" appended- $\sqrt{1+ (f'(x))^2}dx$ is the "differential of arc length".

Comment: "Arc length element function for f" seems to be right on the mark.

Comment: In case anyone is interested in this old unanswered question, I have posted a more general version of it at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501583/is-there-a-name-for-det-jj-top1-2-where-j-is-a-non-square-jacobian-ma